# DocuSign parameterized redirect URI

Tags: docusignapi

IS there a way to have a parameterized ( or a uri with some wild cards) URI set to redirect
URI in the api portal of DocuSign?
From code I would set something like this.

```
ReturnUrlRequest.ReturUrl = "example.com/id=100"
```

On DocuSign API management portal, could I set Redirect URIs

example.com/id=[wildcard]

or

example.com/[wildcard]

where wildcard can be matched to anything?
Thanks

Comment: If your question was answered, be sure to upvote and accept it below! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct. To accomplish this, you can create and edit a custom brand for your signing experience. The Redirect URI (referred here as landing pages) can be customized.

To initialize your new custom brand, use the following endpoint.

```
POST /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/brands
```

Then, in your app logic, you can update the `landingPages` property to your wildcard value. Note that this property accepts an array of name/value pairs specifying the pages to which the user is redirected after the following events occur:

- Signing Completed
- Viewed
- Exit
- Finish Later
- Decline Session
- Timeout
- Authentication Failure

Full Guide on Branding here - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/concepts/branding

Here is the API Reference on Branding - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Accounts/AccountBrands/create

Answer (score 1):

The term `redirect_uri` is used in multiple places within DocuSign systems.

- The redirect uri used as part of the OAuth Authorization Code and Implicit grant flows can not be parameterized.
- The redirect uri's that can be set via branding can include query parameters.
- The redirect uri's used for embedded sending and other embedded flows can include query parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your help!